# Error: Cannot find symbol class in MainActivity.java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

While trying to run my Android application, I receive the following error message:

```
public static class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ToDoItem>
                                                         ^
symbol:   class ToDoItem
location: class MainActivity
```

It took me the last five hours to test various things and ask other students at my university for help but still no solution is found.

**In MainActivity.java:**

```
package androidlab.exercise4_1;

import androidlab.exercise4_1.MainActivity.ListViewAdapter.ToDoItemViewHolder;
import androidlab.exercise4_1.model.ToDoItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ToDoItem>
           implements OnCreateContextMenuListener {

   ...
    }
...
}
```

**In ToDoItem.java:**

```
package androidlab.exercise4_1.model;

public class ToDoItem {

    ...
}
```

As requested here are my gradle files:

- build.gradle (Project: exercise4_1)

  ```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
  buildscript {
      repositories {
          jcenter()
      }
      dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
      }
  }

  allprojects {
      repositories {
          jcenter()
          google()
      }
  }
  ```

  - build.gradle (Module: app)

    ```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "androidlab.exercise4_1"
            minSdkVersion 22
            targetSdkVersion 26
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    }
    ```

Comment: Looks like it can not find a class with name: `ToDoItem`
Check your import statements (very likely on top of the file in MainActivity)

Comment: Having read the question, the only thing that comes to mind is that perhaps you have a non-printing character in your source code (or some other character that looks like a normal one). Have you tried deleting `ToDoItem` in both the class definition and in the MainActivity reference and re-typing it?

Comment: can you ensure that you are able to successfully import "ToDoItem" in the MainActivity class?

Comment: This was an old Eclipse ADT project I imported with Gradle in Android Studio 3.0.1. After resolving all dependencies this is the only error left. Can this happen due to an import problem?

Comment: did you build(sync) the project successfully with gradle? or could you share those gradle files ?

Comment: I put them in the original post.

Comment: gradle file looks fine, so can you sync the project successfully when you click the `sync` button. Also, you can try click `Clean Project` and rebuild again. this may help `http://net-informations.com/java/cjava/symbol.htm`

Comment: @king The sync is successful, cleaning and rebuildung the project via button "make project" works flawlessly. But as soon as I try to run the app I receive the error.
Android Studio also shows no errors at all in the .java-files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler often has problems with nested classes. Your code seems right.
Try to create a new classfile and outsource the class.

Comment: This also solves the problem, thank you.

But this is just a workaround and the better solution is my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved, the import order was wrong.

It had to be

```
import androidlab.exercise4_1.model.ToDoItem;
import androidlab.exercise4_1.MainActivity.ListViewAdapter.ToDoItemViewHolder;
```

instead of

```
import androidlab.exercise4_1.MainActivity.ListViewAdapter.ToDoItemViewHolder;
import androidlab.exercise4_1.model.ToDoItem;
```